# Add custom options to webpack cli for use with a plugin

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm writing a webpack plugin and I'd like to be able to add some custom options to the cli for configuration.

Something like:

```
webpack --my-custom-option string1 string2
```

I can't find any reference to doing this in the docs https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html

Comment: I think you can access to args through `compiler.options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways I saw to do it:

1. Add the param before calling `webpack` and use the `process.env` to access it. For example: `myparam=1231 webpack` in the webpack config file: `process.env.myparam == '1231'`
2. Add the args after the `webpack` command as flags using `--`. For example: `webpack --myparam` in the webpack config file: `process.argv[2] == '--myparam'`

hopes this helps

Comment: exactly that in the end - https://github.com/thebeansgroup/webpack-link/blob/master/index.js#L3-L12 :+1: